# Flask Restful App not loading environment variables using waitress

Tags: python-3.x, flask, environment-variables, waitress

I have a Flask REST app, which used to run via `gunicorn` on an `ubuntu` server, now have to move the deplpoyment to `windows` hence using `waitress` for deployment but its not able to load the env variables:

Project Structure is like:

1. app.py
2. setup.py
3. config.py
4. .env

**.env:**

```
VARIABLE_1=SECRET_1
DB_URL=URL_STRING
```

**config.py**

```
import os;
config = {
   "variable_1": os.getenv("VARIABLE_1")
   "db_url": os.getenv("DB_URL")
}
```

**setup.py** contains all the initaialization logic:

```
// Other Imports

from config import config

def create_app():

    app = FLASK(__name__)
    /* more initialization like CORS, jwt etc  */

    app.config['MONGODB_SETTINGS'] = {
      "host": config['db_url'] // waitress not able to fetch env variables, gunicorn and flask were able to
    }

    /* other stuff */

    return app;
```

**app.py** is the starting point of app:

```
from setup import create_app
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import os
from waitress import serve

if __name == "__main__":
   app = create_app()
   app.run()
else:
   for env_file in ('.env', '.flaskenv'):
     env = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), env_file)
     if os.path.exists(env):
       load_dotenv(env) // here doing os.getenv('env_name') shows value properly but in setup.py they are not loading 
   serve(app, host="some_host")
```

Running application through `waitress-serve` using `waitress-serve app:create_app`

`env` variables are not loading through `config.py` file using `waitress` with `flask` run and `gunicorn` the app runs properly

What do I need to add/fix to make my application work ?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using waitress and dotenv, but to get the env variable you use `os.getenv`, which is fine when running your app with `app.run(...)`, but with waitress you can use `dotenv.get_key('.env', 'MY_ENV_VAR')`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    load_dotenv()

    if os.getenv('PY_ENV') == 'PROD':
        serve(app, listen=f'{os.getenv("HOST")}:{os.getenv("PORT")}')
    else:
        app.run(host=os.getenv('HOST'), port=os.getenv('PORT'), debug=True)
```

this is working, but as I said, with waitress you will not be able to use `os.getenv()`, so you do:

```
dotenv.get_key('.env', 'MY_ENV_VAR')
```

and assuming that you have a .env or something like this in the root of your project, it'll work. I hope it helps.

just so you know, I'm using `python 3.10, waitress=2.1.2, python-dotenv=0.20.0 and Flask=2.0.3`